# Use 2D array as a condition

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scientific-computing

i'm trying to use a 2D array as boolean in an if cycle, cant seem to get it right, it's a large calculation(400,600) so i'm tryng to avoid the use of a double if statement. This is what the code looks like.

```
    if obstacle == 1:

        f1_coll  =f3  
        f2_coll  =f4  
        f3_coll  =f1  
        f4_coll  =f2  

    else:
        f1_coll=tau*(f1 +f2 -f3 +f4 )
        f2_coll =tau*(f1 +f2 +f3 -f4 )
        f3_coll =tau*(-f1 +f2 +f3 +f4 )
        f4_coll =tau*(f1 -f2 +f3 +f4 )
```

all the variables have the same size(400,600) except for tau which is a constant.
Is there ant function that can help me with this?

Comment: Could you describe a little better the control condition you are trying to implement?

Comment: Don't see any boolean, except for the comparison operation in line 1. Please elaborate.

Comment: When you say "array", do you mean `numpy.array`, or `array.array`, or the builtin `list` type often incorrectly called an array, or something else?

Comment: You can check for equality as a boolean `arr1 == expected_arr`

Comment: the array is a numpy array in 2D, "obstacle" with dimension 400x600, the thing is  i just keep getting this message, "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" @mkam

Comment: what i'm trying to do is evaluate each value of the array in order to know where is 0 and where is 1, to the change the value of variables g_coll at that exact position@kpie

Comment: If all variables are arrays, why don't iterate through all the elements? Something like (pseudocode) `for i in obstacle.len(): if osbstacle[i] == 1: f1_coll[i] = f3 else: f1_coll[i] ...`. It would help if you showed a bit more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, I think the following will do the job:

```py
import numpy as np 

# fake variables for the example
obstacle = np.array([[1,0],[1,1]])
f1 = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
f2 = 2*f1
f3 = 3*f1
f4 = 4*f2

tau = 0.5

#here starts the proposed solution
f1_coll = obstacle  * f3 + (obstacle==0) * tau *(f1 +f2 -f3 +f4)
```